# Is this happening because of precision or something else?

Tags: matlab, precision, linear-algebra

I am trying to solve a big linear system, 117 x 117 in Matlab. But every time I run the code, it
gives the output 'NaN' and gives a warning that says *"matrix is singular to working precision"*. Everything else is running well and good. My professor told me to increase the precision of calculation. I have increased it with `digits(64)` function, but even then Matlab is giving me same output. How can I resolve this issue?

I have tried `digits(64)` function to increase precision. I have also tried `linsolve()` function and as usual `\` operator.

Comment: Are you using VPA in your computation? If not, then `digits()` doesn't do anything for you. Please [edit] your post to include a [mre]. Showing us your (minimal) code will help us understand what you're doing and what the problem is.

Comment: So, just increasing digits doesn't solve the root problem of your matrix being near singular. You need to take a step back and ask yourself why that is the case.  Even if you did get an answer of sorts with increased digits, how much would you trust it? Especially in downstream double precision calculations? Instead, look back at how this matrix is formed, maybe examine it with svd( ), etc. to figure out what is going on and then make an appropriate plan for solving your overall problem.

Answer (score 0):

have you checked if maybe your matrix is actually singular? Have you checked rank and determinants?

one way to get around this would be to find a solution with the minimum norm.
numpy does this by default. There is also a matlab function to do this:

`lsqminnorm(A,B)`

once you found a solution you can plug it back in (do a matrix multiplication) and see how close you really are.